# Did anyone have success in configuring Mod security?

Tags: 7

I am trying to set up Mod security (the Apache module) for my Drupal site, but it affects basic Drupal functionalities like node submission, module enable/disable and people permission submissions etc.

I am using:

- Drupal 7.56
- Mod Security 2.91
- Owasp crs 3.0
- Apache 2.4

Did anyone have success in configuring Mod security based on Drupal application?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/695902

Comment: This is highly depending on the rules you have chosen. I have had some issues with rules that were to patch older versions of certain modules, but still applied to the latest version (indeed breaking functionality). The rule id should be in your Apache log, read what it does and decide if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Using OWASP CRS v3.0.2 (https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/releases/tag/v3.0.2) you should find no major issues here. Drupal has it's own set of exclusions out of the box because it does things that can be considered bad practice (passing tags via parameters, etc). As outlined in the docs you should uncomment rule 900130 and enable the Drupal exceptions. There is even an example of how to do so.

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/v3.0/master/crs-setup.conf.example#L302

Enjoy!